# Finding minimum cost - An apple a day

Tags: algorithm

We're given an array containing the prices of apples through N days.
After an apple has been brought, it needs to be consumed within D days.
Another constraint is that we can consume ONLY 1 apple a day.

So we have to find a balance between buying apples when the price is cheap, but also not buying too many that it will be spoiled in D days, and we won't be able to consume them all.
Can anyone suggest which algorithm could be the best for an optimal outcome?

Edit :- Yes, it's necessary to consume an apple a day, and only 1 apple a day.

Comment: Can you clarify the problem? You have an array representing the price of apples. So `[2,5,3]` would be `day 1: $2, day 2: $5, day 3: $3`? And you have a number D which represents the maximum bound of days allowed to eat apples. Considering the 1 apple a day rule, D also represents the maximum total apples allowed to be eaten... So what exactly is the algorithm trying to solve here...

Comment: Must we eat an apple every day? Can we buy some apples in cheap day?

Comment: Waht have **YOU** tried / researched so far? Where did you get stuck? Share **YOUR** findings / ideas / code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To optimize expenses, we need to know minimum in sliding window of length K, ending in every day.

There is O(N) algorithm providing needed results using deque data structure.

Python code. Commented `mins` list contains indices of minimum value in window (for reference). Every day we increment count for the day with the cheapest price in period of K days.

```
from collections import deque

def mininslidingwindow(A, k):
    #mins = []
    buys = [0] * len(A)
    deq = deque()
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if (len(deq) > 0) and (deq[0] <= i - k):
            deq.popleft()  #too old index

        while len(deq) > 0 and A[deq[-1]] >= A[i]:
            deq.pop()  #remove elements having no chance to become a minimum

        deq.append(i)

        #mins.append(deq[0]) #deque head is current min
        buys[deq[0]] += 1

    return buys

print(mininslidingwindow([2,1,5,7,2,8,4,3,4,2], 3))

>>[1, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption:** Assuming we need to eat an apple everyday.

A)
**Algorithm Steps:**

1. Preprocess spans of prices to know till what number of days the price on day **i** will be minimum in future. This process can be done in O(N) for all N days, where N is total days for which we want to plan.
2. Once we have the span till future for all days, we can greedily buy apples on day **i** keeping in mind the constraint of D days. At each day we will see if we can extend the number of days we have covered and buy as many apples required for those days. We extend only if the price at a given day is minimum for such days. This process involves scanning of N days. Hence O(N) time.

**Time Complexity:** The above problem could be solved in O(N) time where N is number of days of data provided.

**Space Complexity:** O(N) for the spans.

B) **Better Algorithm for real time:** Maintain a datastructure to keep data of past **d** days and returns minimum element. Buy an apple every day with minimum price following the criteria of being within d days else discard the price from the datastructure. Time complexity: O(N), Space Complexity: O(D)